# Disable mount namespaces in Apache/PHP-FPM

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mount, namespaces

For a web GUI to manage NFS mount points, we've run into [a problem after migrating to Centos 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596306/device-mounted-by-apache-not-showing-in-shell-mtab-or-proc-mounts).

[JS Billings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3976/jsbillings) noted that:

> CentOS8 runs httpd in a private namespace (with its own private /tmp).
> Since it's such a terrible idea to give httpd the ability to run sudo,
> I've never tried this, but I suspect what you are seeing is the fact
> that the mounts are happening in the private namespace

The effect is that running `mount(8)` via `system()` or even a `setuid` program which calls `mount(2)` to mount NFS partitions, the partitions are only visible to subsequent HTTP calls and not to any processes running on the server itself.

Is there a way to configure `apache` and/or `php-fpm` to not use mount namespaces?

- Centos 8 Kernel 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64
- SELinux is disabled
- Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
- PHP 7.2.11

**EDIT I**

From Michael Hampton's advice, changing `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service` to disable the `PrivateTmp` solved the problem:

```
[Unit]
Description=The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID

# Disable private mount namespace
PrivateTmp=false
RuntimeDirectory=php-fpm
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you not try turning off `PrivateTmp=`? That seems like the first obvious thing.

Comment: Commenting out or setting to 'false' `PrivateTmp` in `httpd.service` did not change anything.  Volumes mounted via PHP are still in their own namespace.

Comment: Well, that has no effect on php-fpm which is its own service!

Comment: Michael, that was it.  If you write an answer I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off `PrivateTmp=` in your `php-fpm.service` to prevent it from getting its own mount namespace. This has security implications, of course, so you may wish to review your code's use of temporary files.